# How to compare string columns w/ logical operation (If (col1 == col2) {true} else {false})

Tags: r, string, if-statement, compare, calculated-columns

So i tried an if else statement but failed...

(I am working with string columns, in R)

```
hostpairs["hostspecificity"] <- NA

If (hostpairs$hostgenus2 == NA){
  hostpairs$hostspecificity == 0
} else if(hostpairs$hostgenus1 == hostpairs$hostgenus2){
  hostpairs$hostspecificity == 1
} else {
  hostpairs$hostspecificity == 2
}
```

> Error in if (hostpairs$hostgenus2 == NA) { :
>     missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
>   In addition: Warning message:
>   In if (hostpairs$hostgenus2 == NA) { :
>     the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

I am pretty sure there is a pretty dumb mistake somewhere in there...

ps. Also if there is a function that checks two string column row by row and comes up with TRUE if they are equal (case insensitive, John = JOHN) or FALSE if they are not equal (John != Mary) That would be very helpful!

Comment: Use `ifelse` rather than `if`.

Comment: what is the difference? and how do i add **else ifs** in ifelse?

Comment: `ifelse` acts on vectors whereas `if` will only work on vectors of length 1 (AKA scalars).  To get multiple levels, you nest `ifelse`. So try `ifelse(x == 1, 1, ifelse(x == 2, 2, 0))` on `x <- -2:2` for a simple example and see `?ifelse` and `?"if"` for a discussion of these functions.

Comment: OK! this works for comparing  two string columns right?

Comment: Yes. Better to compare string columns than factor columns, so make sure that is true with `str(hostpairs)`. If they are factors, convert them to strings (character vectors) using `hostpairs$varname <- as.character(hostpairs$varname)` on each of them and then do the comparison.

Comment: OK! Thanks a lot!! :)